# Odoo set condition OR

Tags: python, module, odoo

in a custom module I have this situation:

```
@api.onchange('barcode')
    def barcode_scanning(self):
        """Barcode decode."""
        if self.barcode:
            scan_barcode = self.barcode
            barcode = scan_barcode
            qty_position = scan_barcode.find("'")
            price_position = scan_barcode.find('/')

            if price_position > 0:
                price = scan_barcode[:price_position].replace(',','.')
                barcode = scan_barcode[price_position + 1:]
            else:
                price = 0

            if qty_position > 0:
                qty = scan_barcode[price_position + 1:qty_position].replace(',','.')
                barcode = scan_barcode[qty_position + 1:]
            else:
                if float(price) > 0:
                    qty = 0
                else:
                    qty = 1
```

I need:  qty_position = scan_barcode.find("'")
command find "'" OR "*".
Can anyone help me, and write me code modified, for find "'" or "*".
I'm not a developer but I user, I don't know how edit this code.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please additional information, like how does the`barcode` looks like.

Comment: Hi  Shibu Tewar, code posted updated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep is simple, I have added an if statement which check if previous `find` function found something that is `qty_position = scan_barcode.find("'")` if it did not find it then `find` if this exist `qty_position = scan_barcode.find("")`
Please see below the code. if this helps.

```
    def barcode_scanning(self):
        """Barcode decode."""
        if self.barcode:
            scan_barcode = self.barcode
            barcode = scan_barcode
            qty_position = scan_barcode.find("'")
            if qty_position < 0:
                qty_position = scan_barcode.find("")
            price_position = scan_barcode.find('/')

            if price_position > 0:
                price = scan_barcode[:price_position].replace(',','.')
                barcode = scan_barcode[price_position + 1:]
            else:
                price = 0

            if qty_position > 0:
                qty = scan_barcode[price_position + 1:qty_position].replace(',','.')
                barcode = scan_barcode[qty_position + 1:]
            else:
                if float(price) > 0:
                    qty = 0
                else:
                    qty = 1
```